# Type casting to an interface (Abstract class) in case of Multiple Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

```
class Widget{ .. }  // Widget Class

class Interface { // pure virtual functions .. } // Interface class (Abstract Class)

class WidgetType1 : public Widget, public Interface { ... } // Type 1 Widget (ComboBox) inherits widget and Interface
class WidgetType2 : public Widget, public Interface { ... } // Type 2 Widget (LineEdit) inherits widget and Interface

Widget* widget = getWidget(...);
Interface* interface = dynamic_cast<Interface*> (widget); // Convert Widget to Interface
```

What I should to do access methods of Interface on object of Widget (which is basically a WidgetType 1/2)

I am unable to type cast object of WidgetType1 referenced by pointer of Widget

[image: Image for Design]

Comment: Tell us the error or specific problems. *"I am unable to type cast object ..."* is NOT enough.

Comment: If you get a compiler error then my guess is that you need to add parentheses to the dynamic_cast: `dynamic_cast<Interface*>(widget)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm making my comment into an answer: My guess is that you get a compiler error because you forgot to add parentheses to the `dynamic_cast`:

```
Interface* interface = dynamic_cast<Interface*>(widget)
```

For `dynamic_cast` to work correctly at runtime, you need to compile your project with RTTI (run-time type information, [link to Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)). I may be mistaken, but I believe compilers enable RTTI by default, so you should know if you have disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess as you didn't show us the implementation of `class Widget` or describe the nature of the error.

```
class Widget{ ... };  // Widget Class
...
Interface* interface = dynamic_cast<Interface*> (widget);
```

Note that I added a missing semicolon to the end of your class specification. This alone may be the cause of your problems.

Another possibility: Your comment for class `Interface` specifically indicates that virtual methods are defined for that class. Your comment for class `Widget` says nothing of the sort. `Widget` is not a polymorphic class you don't define any virtual methods for the class. The only thing you can dynamically cast a pointer to a non-polymorhic class into is a parent class pointer. `Interface` is not a parent class of `Widget`, making the dynamic class is illegal if `Widget` doesn't have any virtual methods.